# twitter typeahead.js process() call not working asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, typeahead.js

I'm using the standalone UI view.

```
http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.jquery.min.js
```

I'm attempting to asynchronously query addresses and show the suggestions like this:

```
$('#inputBox').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 3
        },
        {
            name: 'places',
            source: evnt.addressSuggest
        });
```

///////////////////////

```
addressSuggest: function(query, process){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://XXXXXX",
        data: {
                    prefix: query,
                },
        dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function(data){
                var suggestions = data.suggestions;

                var onlyText = $.map(suggestions, function(n, i){ return n.text; });


                process(onlyText); 
                })
.error(function(){alert('an error occurred');}); 

},
```

The above doesn't show any suggestions. If I put a logging statement above or below where process() is being invoked, it gets executed. But the call to process doesn't seem to do anything.

But when I make the AJAX call synchronous and invoke process() as follows:

```
addressSuggest: function(query, process){
    var onlyText;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://XXXXXX",
        data: {
                    prefix: query,
                },
        dataType: 'json',
        async:   false
        }).done(function(data){
                var suggestions = data.suggestions;

                onlyText = $.map(suggestions, function(n, i){ return n.text; });

                })
.error(function(){alert('an error occurred');}); 

    process(onlyText);
},
```

then I can see the suggestions. Of course the issue with synchronous requests is that the UI gets blocked. Why is the async version not working?

P.S. I also tried changing the data structure from an array of strings to something like `[{'value': 'first'}, {'value': 'second'}, {'value': 'third'}]` as suggested by some other answers to other questions but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use the three parameters version of the function, such as
function (query, process, asyncProcess) and then use the third parameter, asyncProcess on the data instead of the second.

So you would do `asyncProcess(data)` instead of `process(data)`.

Answer (score 1):

I also could not get async remote source to work with typeahead.js , removed the bloodhound code (calling typeahead.jquery.min.js), and wrote my own remote data source code for typeahead that actually works. Here is my own code that works flawlessly, except gets the data synchronously: [typeahead.js ajax remote data source only works with synchronous ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601152/typeahead-js-ajax-remote-data-source-only-works-with-synchronous-ajax-request)

To make this async, your datasource function needs a third parameter for typeahead to call when the async request is complete.  Your revised function definition would look as follows (notice the third parameter): 
`addressSuggest: function(query, process, process){`

Adding the third parameter and setting "async: true" will show the results using async.  Here is the documentation that explains the need for the third parameter in the definition for `source`: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets