# typeahead.js ajax remote data source only works with synchronous ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, typeahead.js

Typeahead.js only works with a custom ajax remote data source when submitting the request synchronously, not asynchronously. When submitted asynchronously (async: true), my script and custom TABoards() function is done executing before the cb() function can propagate the list of results.  My code below works flawlessly and produces results from two data sources: a remote ajax data source and a "static" data source that always produces a single "View all results for [query]" result.  However, the resulting code also produces the following notice in the browser javascript console: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience."  Adding ".done(function(){cb(response)});" did not work.

How can I rewrite this code to function the exact same except not produce the browser notice?

```
var TABoards = function(q, cb){
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    url: '/typeahead.php?q='+q+'&type=boards',
    success: function(response){
      cb(response);
    }
  });
}
$('#hdrSrchQ').typeahead({
  highlight: true,
  hint: false,
  minLength: 3
}, {
  name: 'ta-boards',
  displayKey: 'title',
  source: TABoards,
  templates: {
    header: '<h4>Boards</h4>',
    suggestion: function(data){
      return '<a href="/'+ data.name  +'">' + data.title + ' - ' + data.name + '</a>';
    }
  }
},{
  name: 'ta-viewall',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: function(q, cb){
    cb([{'value': q}]);
  },
  templates: {
    suggestion: function(data) {
      return '<a href="/?q=' + data.value + '">View all results for ' + data.value + '...</a>';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: **Solved**: Typeahead.js has weak documentation, which is why this didn't work asynchronously.  The documentation at https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets says this about the dataset source parameter:

Expected to be a function with the signature (query, syncResults, asyncResults). syncResults should be called with suggestions computed synchronously and asyncResults should be called with suggestions computed asynchronously (e.g. suggestions that come for an AJAX request).

Comment: **Solved** Async data source require a third parameter, which is the callback function for the async request. So my revised definition for function TABoards() is as follows:

`var skryTABoards = function(q, cb, cb){`

The third parameter cb is the callback function when the async data is received, which will show the async results on the suggestion list.